# com.lamudi.phonefield.PhoneEditText spinner black color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Good Day, I am using lamudi-gmbh/android-phone-field  for phone number validation and i am getting spinner data in black background and i want to replace it with white color background [image: normal] [image: Picture here]

```
    <com.lamudi.phonefield.PhoneEditText

        android:id="@+id/home_phone_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_home_number"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        />
```

Comment: @VishalThakkar thats not duplicate of that because android:popupbackground is not working in my case and i am using other lib and that guy is using other

Comment: Then change your question  with proper  explanation. its not spinner then you should not write in question

Comment: @VishalThakkar changed the title now do you know the solution?

Comment: have you check in real device?

Comment: that's real device image i am making another project where its working fine but on my project it will give that black color

Comment: Put Your full layout xml

Comment: @VishalThakkar here is my full xml https://pastebin.com/DSxbDsi3

Answer (score 0):

Change layout:margin to layout:padding

Comment: i am using constraints layout so i won't be able to remove it